# "vel" in Tusculan Disputations V.iii

Tags: vocabulary, idiom, conjunction, cicero

In the *Tusculan Disputations* V.iii, Cicero writes about Pythagoras declaring that life seems to him like the great Greek games:

> Nam ut illic alii corporibus exercitatis gloriam et nobilitatem coronæ peterent, alii emendi aut vendendi quæstu et lucro ducerentur, esset autem quoddam genus eorum, idque **vel** maxime ingenuum, qui nec plausum nec lucrum quærerent, sed visendi causa venirent studuiosque perspicerent quid agitur et quo modo…

How is *vel* working in this sentence and what does it mean? Without *vel* I would translate the relevant portion something like "there was however a certain class of them, and that of the highest character, who sought neither applause nor money," etc. But I don't know what the addition of *vel* does.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

It's a way of intensifying the superlative: "of the very highest..."

[L&S, s.v. *vel*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dvel), II.B: " With superlatives, to denote the highest possible degree, the very; the utmost; the most...possible."